# Creating PDF from images in a folder in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, image, fpdf

I have about 16 JPG files in a folder in Jupyter Notebook that I would like to compile into 1 PDF, but only in a certain order. Like in my folder with the JPGs, I have a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4, and so on. I would like to put all 4 files beginning with 'a' in 1 page of the PDF, files beginning with 'b' on the next page in the PDF, and so on.

I tried this :

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
# imagelist is the list with all image filenames
for image in imagelist:
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(image,x,y,w,h)
pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```

But I'm not sure how to get the files and put them in a list to carry this out, or how I can arrange them in the way I want to arrange them.
Thanks to anyone that answers!

Answer (score 0):

If your images are named as you said, you could do something like this. Define the x,y,w,h based on the position you want them on the page

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
dims = [
    (x, y,w,h),
    (x, y,w,h),
    (x, y,w,h),
    (x, y,w,h)
]

for image_type in set([i[0] for i in image_list]):
    imgs = list(filter(lambda x:image_type in x,image_list))
    pdf.add_page()
    for i,j in zip(imgs,dims):
        pdf.image(i,j[0],j[1],j[2],j[3])
pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```